# derive from foreign xml schema

Tags: xml, import, xsd, include, xml-encryption

This is an xml example I want to be able to validate with my selfmade schema.
The whole `EncryptedData` part is actually syntax of the XML Encryption specification.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foo xmlns="http://www.foo.org/FOO">
    <EncryptedData>
        <EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:KeyName>John Smith</ds:KeyName>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>DEADBEEF</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</Foo>
```

So I tried deriving from XML Encryption and came up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xenc='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#'
    xmlns:xenc11="http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#"
    xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/Foo"
    targetNamespace="http://www.foo.org/Foo">
    <xsd:import namespace='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#' />
    <xsd:import namespace='http://www.w3.org/2009/xmlenc11#' />
    <xsd:element name="Foo">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="myItem" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="anyType"/>
                <xsd:element ref="xenc:EncryptedData" minOccurs="1"
                    maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

But then my actual xml would have to look like this. I need to prefix all the XML Encryption elements with namespaces as I imported them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo
    xmlns="http://www.foo.org/Foo"
    xmlns:xenc='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#'/>
    <xenc:EncryptedData>
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod
            Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:KeyName>John Smith</ds:KeyName>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>DEADBEEF</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</foo>
```

But I also fail to actually change the import into an include as target namespaces differ. (my own being different from the one defined in the xml encryption schema)
Is there a way to do this so you can even use it without the namespaces?
Or will it only work with prefixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the default namespace in the root element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2014 Developer Bundle Edition 12.1.2.5004 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<fns:foo xmlns:fns="http://www.foo.org/Foo"
         xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#'>
    <EncryptedData>
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:KeyName>John Smith</ds:KeyName>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>DEADBEEF</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</fns:foo>
```

Or you can change the default element several times removing all the prefixes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2014 Developer Bundle Edition 12.1.2.5004 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<foo xmlns="http://www.foo.org/Foo">
    <EncryptedData xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#'>
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>John Smith</KeyName>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>DEADBEEF</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</foo>
```

Comment: I took the second option that works well with XML Encryption at least. Unfortunately I'm getting "The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element" when trying this with my own schema. Anyway it seems to work though! Thanks

Comment: The error I was getting was because eclipse set the wrong namespace name in the xml catalog.